# Laravel/Doctrine randomly tries to connect to production database

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, laravel-doctrine

I'm randomly getting server errors because Laravel is trying to connect to the production database, despite the fact that I have a `.env` file set up and a majority of the time it connects to the correct database.

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
[2018-02-17 08:05:54] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = settings) {"exception":"[object]
(Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000]
[1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = settings) at C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:664,
Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000]
[1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at
C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:47,
PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at
C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\lib\\Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection.php:43)
```

Why would doctrine be trying to connect to the wrong database? Is it being insantiated before dotenv sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

**First**

You can try clear or re-cache your configurations
`php artisan config:clear` or `php artisan config:cache`

before running your migration commands

**Secondly**

I had this issue on heroku. When trying to run migration commands from heroku's ssh `heroku ps:exec` environment. i was doing:

`heroku ps:exec`
and 
`php artisan migrate`

but the env variables set in the heroku app isn't available to laravel (`env('DB_DATABASE')`, etc).

To fix this, i had to run the migrations from the bash

`heroku run bash`

then

`php artisan migrate`